# Compare two tables from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have to compare two tables , then list all of them as check boxes, while matched values should be checked and non matching without checked

**//table 1**

```
rid| role_name  
1  |    school  
2  |    college  
3  |  University
```

**//table2**

```
id|rid | category  
1 | 1  |  uniform  
2 | 2  |  uniform
```

match rid from both table where category = 'uniform'
list all and checked the matching rid

Comment: Cycle through each row in table 1. If `rid` exists in table 2, tick.

Comment: I have to do my job too. Any volunteers?

Comment: Do a outer join between two tables based on rid and category filter. And what ever has category value uniform mark it tick and category with null leave it unmarked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $query = "select t1.rid, 'matched' as matching from table1 t1 where t1.rid  in (
              select rid from table2 where category = 'uniform')
             union
             select t1.rid ,'notmatched' from table1 t1 where t1.rid not in (
             select rid from table2 where category = 'uniform')";
    $result = mysqli->query($query);
    $fetched = $result->fetch_assoc();
    foreach($fetched as $row){
    if($row['matching'] = 'matched'){
           echo "<input type='checkbox' name='{$row['rid']}' value='' checked='checked' >"; }
    else{ 
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='{$row['rid']}' value=''  >"; }
     }
```

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55a40/14)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select a.* from table1 a, table b where a.rid = b.rid and a.category = b.category";

$result = mysqli->query($query);

$fetched = $result->fetch_assoc();

foreach($fetched as $row){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='{$row['rid']}' value='' checked > {$row['category']}";
}
```